# How to implement custom pattern layout in log4j2

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, log4j, log4j2

I am migrating my application from `log4j` to `log4j2` API. While migration, I found `custom` `patternlayouts`, `patternparsers` and `patternconverters` are used. I am not aware of how to implement these changes using log4j2 plugins. Can anyone help me on how to convert this custom layout `TestPatternLayout` to log4j2. Many thanks.

PFB the complete details on how custom pattern layout is implemented using `log4j`.

**TestPatternLayout:**

```
public class TestPatternLayout extends PatternLayout {

@Override 
protected PatternParser createPatternParser(String pattern) { 
    return new TestPatternParser(pattern); 
 } 
}
```

**TestPatternParser:**

```
public class TestPatternParser extends PatternParser {

private static final char Test_CHAR = 'e';
private static final char DATETIME_CHAR = 'd';

public TestPatternParser(String pattern) {
    super(pattern);
}

@Override
protected void finalizeConverter(char c) {
    switch (c) {
        case Test_CHAR:
            currentLiteral.setLength(0);
            addConverter(new TestPatternConverter());
            break;            
        default:
            super.finalizeConverter(c);
    }
 }
}
```

**TestPatternConverter:**

```
public class TestPatternConverter extends PatternConverter {

@Override
protected String convert(LoggingEvent event) {
    String testID = ObjectUtils.EMPTY_STRING;
    if(TestLogHandler.isTestLogEnabled()) {
        TestContextHolder contextHolder = TestLogHandler.getLatestContextHolderFromStack(event.getThreadName());
        if(contextHolder != null) {
            testID = contextHolder.getTestIDForThread(event.getThreadName());
        }
        else{
            testID = TestContextHolder.getTestIDForThread(event.getThreadName());
        }
    }
    return testID;
 }
}
```

**Layout definition in log4j.xml:**

```
<appender name="TEST_LOG_FILE" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
...
   <layout class="com.test.it.logging.TestPatternLayout">
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p [%c{1}] [TestId: %e] [%t] %m%n"/>
</layout>
...
</appender>
```

Answer (score 7):

You just need to create a new `Plugin` and extend `LogEventPatternConverter`:

```
@Plugin(name = "TestPatternConverter", category = PatternConverter.CATEGORY)
@ConverterKeys({"e"})
public final class TestPatternConverter extends LogEventPatternConverter {

    /**
     * Private constructor.
     * @param options options, may be null.
     */
    private TestPatternConverter(final String[] options) {
        super("TestId", "testId");
    }

    /**
     * Obtains an instance of pattern converter.
     *
     * @param options options, may be null.
     * @return instance of pattern converter.
     */
    public static TestPatternConverter newInstance(final String[] options) {
        return new TestPatternConverter(options);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public void format(final LogEvent event, final StringBuilder toAppendTo) {
        String testID = ObjectUtils.EMPTY_STRING;
        if(TestLogHandler.isTestLogEnabled()) {
            TestContextHolder contextHolder = TestLogHandler.getLatestContextHolderFromStack(event.getThreadName());
            if(contextHolder != null) {
                testID = contextHolder.getTestIDForThread(event.getThreadName());
            }
            else{
                testID = TestContextHolder.getTestIDForThread(event.getThreadName());
            }
        }
        toAppendTo.append(testID);
    }
}
```

and update your configuration:

```
<Appender type="RollingFile" name="TEST_LOG_FILE" fileName="${filename}">
      <Layout type="PatternLayout">
        <Pattern>%d %-5p [%c{1}] [TestId: %e] [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
      </Layout>
</Appender>
```

That should be all. Please see [Extending log4j2](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/extending.html)
 for more details.

Comment: Great answer! It is possible to hide/unhide throwable's message using this?

Comment: What is `TestLogHandler.isTestLogEnabled()` and where I should set a value for this condition?

Comment: hey @Praytic, it is this one https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.guava/guava-testlib/latest/com/google/common/testing/TestLogHandler.html form Guava